# Save Contact on API call

Tags: xdb, xconnect

Here is my scenario - on the page, there will be a button, on the button click there will be a popup and the user will enter some detail. On submit button, I need to create a contact and save custom facets on xDB and after that, there will be a confirmation message on the same popup.

Because I do not want to post back the page, I am doing an ajax call, and `Tracker` will not be available on `ServicesApiController`. Is there any solution to this?

Code:

```
public class SubscriptionApiController : ServicesApiController
    {
        private readonly IContactRepository _contactRepository;

        public SubscriptionApiController()
        {
            _contactRepository = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContactRepository>(); 
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(SubscriptonModel model)
        {
            try
            {
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Constants.ErrorMessage.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
```

Route

```
 public class WebApiServices
    {
        public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Configure);
        }
        protected void Configure(HttpConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var routes = configuration.Routes;
            routes.MapHttpRoute("subscriptionApi", "api/{controller}/{action}", new { });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a custom route to a regular sitecorecontroller using:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute( "yourcustomroute", "custom/path", new { controller = "yourcontroller", action = "youraction" } );
```

Then call that via an ajax call.

By doing it this way, it is like navigating to that page in the normal session and sitecore tracker is available.

This article covers the main points involved in setting this up:

https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-configure-custom-goals-and-trigger-them-by-ajax-call-sitecore/

Comment: I have added my code, which is not working for me

Comment: I see you must have got it working. The key is to use normal controller, not apicontroller.

Comment: Yes after using SitecoreController, it is working